# How to describe a summation of $\frac{1}{2^x3^y}$ and evaluate.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, notation

I want too calculate the value of this sum:

$$\sum  \frac{1}{2^x3^y}$$

Where we sum up all permutations of terms involving a nonnegative integer $x$ and a nonnegative integer $y$.

How can I notationally describe this sum and how can I calculate it (assuming it does converge).

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be a double sum?

Comment: I need to add up all possible permutations, so I don't think that's the same thing. But what do you think @GeorgSaliba

Comment: Then it's a double sum, separate the 2 and 3, then use the sum of a geometric series...

Comment: Addressing the edit that was just made: the sum $$\sum \frac{1}{2^x 3^y}$$ is a bit different than summing over each index individually; i.e., when you do the double sum, you are really integrating over the product space $\mathbb N_0 \times \mathbb N_0$ with the counting measure on that space. However, in this case, since all terms are positive, Tonelli's theorem allows you to compute the double sum by summing in one variable first and then the other (i.e., integrating in $\mathbb N_0$ with the counting measure, and then doing the same with the other variable).

Comment: If, e.g., the sum was not absolutely convergent, the iterated sums may both still converge but take different values; in that case, the distinction is important. For this problem, yes, it's just an iterated sum, first in $x$ and then in $y$ (or $m,n$ if that is what you prefer).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't make that edit. But I think I'll change it back so that people who are view this post will see exactly what my question was. @User8128

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to the Fubini/Tonelli Theorem, you can just sum over one index first, and then over the other. That is,
$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n 3^m} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac 1 {2^n}\left(\sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac 1{3^y} \right) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac 1 {2^n} \left(\frac{1}{1-(1/3)}\right) = \frac 3 2 \cdot\frac{1}{1-(1/2)} = 3.$$ It'd be the exact same if you summed over $n$ first, then $m$.